# Background processing video uploads, what is a proficient way in PHP?

Tags: php, process, background, ffmpeg

I am developing a video upload site and I have ran into a dilemma: videos uploaded need to be converted into the FLV format in order to be displayed to a visitor but, if I execute the command within the script, the script will hang for about 10-15 minutes while the FFMPEG converts the video.

I had an idea to insert a record in to the database indicating the file needs to be processed, then using a cron job set to every 5 minutes to select records from the database which needs to be processed, process them, then update the database showing they have been processed. My worry about this is executing too many processes and the server crashing under the strain, so has anyone got any solutions to this or a way to better the process I have in mind?

---

Okay, this is now what I have in mind, so the user uploads a video and a row is inserted in to the database indicating the video needs to be processed. A cron job set to every 5 minutes checks what needs to be processed and what is being processed, say I would make a maximum of five processes at one time, so the script would check if any video needs to be processed and how many videos are being processed, if it is less then five, it updates the record indicating that it is being processed, once the video has been processed, it updates the record indicating it has been processed and the cron job starts again, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect a lot of traffic you should seriously consider a dedicated server.

On a single server, you can use `shell_exec` along with the UNIX `nohup` command to get the PID of the process.

```
   function run_in_background($Command, $Priority = 0)
   {
       if($Priority)
           $PID = shell_exec("nohup nice -n $Priority $Command 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
       else
           $PID = shell_exec("nohup $Command 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
       return($PID);
   }
   function is_process_running($PID)
   {
       exec("ps $PID", $ProcessState);
       return(count($ProcessState) >= 2);
   }
```

A full description of this technique is here: http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/

You could perhaps put the list of PIDs in a MySQL table and then use your cron job every 5 mins to detect when a video is complete and update the relevant values in the database.

Answer (score 3):

[Gearman](http://php.net/gearman) is a good solution for this kind of problem, it lets you instantly dispatch a job and have any number of workers (which may be on different servers) available to fulfill it.

To start with you can run a few workers on the same server, but if you start to run into load issues then you can just fire up another server with some more workers, so it's horizontally scalable.

Comment: It's seem a little too advanced for what I had in mind now, but I will definitely be looking to use it in the future if there is a substantial amount of traffic towards the server.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP-FPM then you can make use of *fastcgi_finish_request()* as documented on PHP.net. [FastCGI Process Manager (FPM)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)

> **fastcgi_finish_request()** - special function to finish request and flush all data while continuing to do something time-consuming (video converting, stats processing etc.);

If you're not using PHP-FPM or want something more advanced then you might consider using a queue manager like [Gearman](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse-bg.php) which is perfectly suited to the scenario you're describing. The advantage of using Gearman over running a process with shell_exec is you can take a look at how many jobs are running / how many are left and check their statuses. You also make scaling much easier as it's now trivial to add job servers:

```
$worker->addServer("10.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 1):

I love this class (see the specific comment) in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#88704

Basically, it lets you spin off a background process on *Nix systems.  it returns a `pid`, which you can store in the session.  When you reload the page to check on it, you simply recreate the `ForkedProcess` class with the saved `pid`, and you can check on it's status.  If it's complete, the process should be done.

It doesn't allow for much error checking, but it's incredibly lightweight.

Comment: It's a function, not a class.

Comment: The specific comment I linked to was for a Process class.  Sorry if that isn't clear.

Comment: My bad, the page did not scroll to the comment first time around.

Answer (score 0):

You can call ffmpeg use `system` and send the output to `/dev/null`, this will make that call return right away, effectively handling it in the background.

Comment: I thought of doing that but I had a couple of worries:

1. If many people are trying to upload videos at the same time, the server may crash with the load put on it as there is no effective way of controlling the amount of processes spawned.

2. How would I be able to report back to the user once the file has been converted? I assume I could get the process ID and have a cron job check if this process has terminated, then update the database?

Answer (score 0):

Spawn couple of worker processes which will consume messages from message queue like for example [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/). This way you can control the number of concurrent tasks(conversions) and also don't have to pay price of spawning processes(because processes keep running in background).

I think it would be even a lot faster if you used/coded C and used [Redis](http://redis.io) as your message queue. Redis has a very good c client library named [Hiredis](https://github.com/antirez/hiredis). I don't think this would be insanely difficult to accomplish.